# Extraer el valores concretos de un json response

Tags: python, python-requests

intente obtener el valor de todos los campos "id" de lo que obtengo a través de una api de idbm mediante el siguiente codigo:

```
import requests

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

resp = response.json()

print(resp[0])
```

obtuve lo siguiente:

```
[{"episodes":[{"episode":1,"id":"/title/tt4917582/","season":1,"title":"Unauthorized Magic","titleType":"tvEpisode","year":2015},{"episode":2,"id":"/title/tt4976372/","season":1,"title":"The Source of Magic","titleType":"tvEpisode","year":2016}}]
```

intente obtenerlo mediante `print(resp['id'])` pero me da error de que el indice no puede ser string, el caso es que he buscado como obtener valores de jsons y solo encuentro esta forma...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu mismo estás haciendo `resp[0]` y obteniendo ese resultado... Esto te indica que `resp` es un array y posee varios elementos dentro, el primer elemento en este caso es el que estás imprimiendo, al ser un `array` no puedes accederlo por medio de una string tal y como dice el error (los diccionarios son los que se acceden con strings).

Por esto es que tu código funciona cuando haces `resp[0]` por que accedes el array de la manera debida, por medio de un número índice... Ahora si quisieras acceder a todos los elementos del id tienes que ver la estructura que tiene tu `resp[0]`, la cual corresponde a un array, con un diccionario único dentro, el cuál contiene una entrada llamada `episodes`, esta entrada contiene un array (los episodios). Para acceder a esta entrada entonces debes de hacer:

```
episodios = resp[0][0]["episodes"]
```

Y lo que contendría esta variable sería un array de diccionarios que corresponde a cada episodio, para recorrerlos e imprimir los `id` podrías hacer:

```
for episodio in episodios :
    print(episodios ["id"])
```